# Incorrect check for equality with localStorage items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, local-storage

I've got this code:

```
let storedItem = localStorage.getItem('current_tenant');
console.log(storedItem);  // is undefined
if (storedItem !== undefined) {
  console.log('why');
  let retrievedTenant = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current_tenant') || '');
  setCurrentTenant(retrievedTenant);
}
```

Weirdly, the code within the `if` statement still runs. I've tried different combinations of this, including `!== undefined`, `!= null`, and `typeof ___ != 'undefined'`, but the code block inside the statement always runs.

Why is this? Is it something to do with `localStorage`?

Comment: You should check for `null`, not `undefined`.

Comment: just try, if ( !storedItem ), it will check undefined as well as null.

Comment: Are you sure that `storedItem` is not the string `"undefined"`?

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the string, "undefined", lol. @unmitigated thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Don't check if storedItem is `undefined` but check if it's `null`.

```
if (!storedItem)
```